# Distinction between X-ray damage and improper handling during development

Tags: film, developing, scanning

I finished processing a roll of Fomapan 100 (using df96) and found some of the frames had vertical stripes (perpendicular to the film's moving direction in the camera):

[image: stripes at bottom]

[image: stripes at bottom]

(The scan was done using the JJC 135 camera scan kit, using a Sigma 105mm Macro on an EOS R6 II, pardon me the dust and debris during scanning)

But this phenomenon does not seem to appear on all frames and showed no pattern, the same roll also has many frames that do not show any sign of stripes:

[image: unaffected]

I also did not find any pattern in the intervals between frames with stripes, some are next to each other, and some are separated by several frames.

This roll of Fomapan came with an international shipment that could have gone through an X-ray. So I am wondering what is the cause of these stripes, X-ray damage, or a possible error during my development?

Comment: The strength of airport X-ray scans has reduced significantly in the last 20 years. Back then film could get damaged, now not so much so I would exclude that cause.

Comment: @FarO X-ray scanning of hand luggage is largely harmless for photographic film (unless the film goes through multiple passes - the effects are cumulative). X-ray scanning of checked luggage is stronger, and should certainly be avoided for film. New CT scanners are being phased in for hand luggage - Kodak strongly advises against putting film through these scanners. I am sure that (some) mail gets x-rayed, but I've no idea of the strengths involved.

Comment: At least on the first photo, it is clear that the stripes are not necessarily perpendicular to the direction of film movement, but at least in the left part of the image slanted and perhaps even slightly curved. It is not at all unlikely that these are damages from some kind of x-ray or CT scanner with a rotating beam.

Comment: @FarO The situation is exactly opposite. New CT scanners used in airport security have a much stronger beam than previously used x-ray equipment and film manufacturers like e.g. Kodak, point out that these scanners *will* damage unprocessed film.

Comment: just FYI, I read an article today that London City airport has replaced all X-ray scanners with CT scanners. So film photographers beware. Other UK airports will all do the same by June 2024. If you're wondering whether your film is going through X-ray or CT, the giveaway seems to be the restriction on liquids; London City airport allows 2 litres of liquids in hand luggage now, and I think it doesn't have to be presented separately in a plastic bag anymore. Don't allow your film to go through one of these scanners.